# AWS Lambda error message "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.7

I am trying to upload a zip file to AWS lambda but keep getting the error "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'"

I've started very basic by creating a zip file named "lambda_function.zip" with one file inside "lambda_function.py". At a later stage I will need to include packages in the zip file, but for now it's a very simple function named lambda_handler only using json.

Once uploaded this is the file structure and the error message received after testing:
[code and error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p4vQ.png)

If I move lamda_function.py into the root folder "RWS-POC" then it works, but later on when I need to upload a larger zip file this won't be an option as editing via the interface is disabled.

I can also confirm that the handler is set to lambda_function.lambda_handler and the python file is named "lambda_function" and the function named "lambda_handler"
[lambda_function.lambda_handler settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dTQE.png)

I'm sure I'm doing something very basic wrong, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lambda_function.py` is inside folder called `lambda_function`. Just **move** your `lambda_function` to `RWS-POC`, or modify handler into:

```
lambda_function/lambda_function.lambda_handler
```

Comment: just realised I was zipping the driectory rather than the contents of the directory! thanks !